# How do I get it so when I double click a py file it opens up Idle to edit without a console window temporarily coming up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I've been trying to search stack overflow and Reddit to find out how to do it as I did it years ago, where if I double-clicked on a py file, it would open in idle without a console window temporarily opening up and closing.

I tried to follow the steps in this video, but the registry seems to have changed so can't.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l370kEUhXko&ab_channel=JaradPython

any advice on how to do this? I seem to have lost the "edit with idle" option on the right-click menu as well once I changed it to open with idle.bat. Not sure how this affects everything.

I am using the latest Python 3.11.4

Thank you

Comment: This does not sound like a programming question. Try posting this to superuser.com. Also, be more explicit regarding the operating system you are using and which particular version.

Comment: Sorry am on windows 11.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on https://discuss.python.org/c/users/7, with more details given.

Answer (score 0):

If it's closing immediately after running the  file, consider adding an input statement at the end of the code so that it doesn't actually close.

```
print("hello world")
prompt= input()
```

Now the console will remain open until you enter something.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I'm not running the file. I'm just opening the file in idle to edit. I'd like for the console to not appear at all when I double click the python file. Which I somehow figured out how to do before but can't remember now.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you were asking a way to keep the console open.